# QgsVectorDataProvider.createAttributeIndex() fails in QGis 1.8

Tags: qgis-plugins, pyqgis

Adding an Attribute Index to a Shapefile fails for a Python Plugin in QGIS:

For example - the following python Code in a Plugin

```
ly = QgsVectorLayer(data_source, layer_name,"ogr")
prov = ly.dataProvider()
prov.createAttributeIndex(i)
```

results in the error Message:

> 'QgsVectorDataProvider' object has no attribute 'createAttributeIndex'

Whereas Adding a Spatial Index works without any problem

```
ly = QgsVectorLayer(data_source, layer_name,"ogr")
prov = ly.dataProvider()
prov.createSpatialIndex()
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: The above Error message appears with the QGIS 1.8.0 standard build on Windows. Meanwhile I tested this piece of code with QGIS 1.8.0 on Debian, too. The result was the same Error. ('QgsVectorDataProvider' object has no attribute 'createAttributeIndex'). Seams that this Method doesn't work for Objects created with Python. In Addition, it seams that an attribute index has no influence on the performance of queries in QGIS, at least for shapefiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method is not exposed to python in QGis 1.8, but it is in the current development (master) release.

Please be aware, that before calling createAttributeIndex(), you should check the provider capabilities:

```py
if prov.capabilities() & QgsVectorDataProvider.CreateAttributeIndex:
```

but for the ogr provider this is implemented and if you are sure you are always dealing with this data provider this step can safely be skipped.

If you notice no performance impact after creating an index, that is most likely a problem in the provider, as QGis itself does no indexing and only forwards the create index request to the data provider.